# bulk importing data in articles node catagory based

Tags: nodes

Hello how to bulk Import XML feeds -Content from xml systems category base to drupal

Hello I have custom CMS we are moving to Drupal.Our custom CMS has bulk post system via XML feed.
We post 1000 articles/News via xml per hour on our CMS.

We need to know how to import bulk xml as Categories (Taxonomy) base.

Here is our xml file below

`Sports
  Title
  Image Location
  
    Bulgaria votes in parliamentary poll
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    tag1,tag2,tag3
    2/15/2015 8:26:01 AM
  
  
     Sports
    Youssou Ndour awarded Polar Prize
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua.Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
    tag1,tag2,tag3
    2/15/2015 8:26:01 AM`

Answer (score 0):

Using [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) and [Feeds XPath Parser](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser) will do the trick. I would also take a look at [Feeds Tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper). I have used it myself in the past and it works very wel!

Here is also a [basic tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/1542294) to get you started.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for reply.Can provide a xml file format So We can test?

Comment: Just create a test XML to work with it.
If my answer helped you please is as an answer so users with the same problems in the future know this worked for you.